# Modify circleci/android docker container

Tags: android, docker, circleci, android-build

I'm spiking CircleCI for Android builds. So far so good, can get the build going as expected. I now want to modify the `circleci/android:api-26-alpha` image to put in my app's keystore file so I can sign builds from there.

How I'm planning to do this is:

1. Run the image in a container locally
2. Copy my keystore file to relevant directory
3. Push the image to my new repo
4. Use this new image for builds

The problem I'm having is with step 1. I can get the image to my local with
`docker run --name android circleci/android:api-26-alpha` but it doesn't start. When I try `docker start android` nothing happens, the `docker ps --all` output shows status as exited, indicating it pretty much stops straight away. I try and get some info with `docker logs android` but nothing is printed.

I'm sure I'm just missing some extra params or something when trying to start the container but I don't know how to find out what.

Has anyone got any tips? Alternatively, are there other android build containers I can look at with a bit more documentation perhaps?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to open in the end with command: `docker run -d -t circleci/android:api-26-alpha /bin/bash`